# Trying to do sumifs formula that calculates multiplication as well

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Sumifs formula that i am trying to have the sum range be multiplication between two columns. It is giving me an error stating "There's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? etc."
My formula looks like this:

```
=sumifs(sum($I$4:$I$32*$C$4:$C$32),W3,$E$4:$E$32)
```

What is wrong with this formula?

Comment: I have changed my formula to: =SUMIFS(I4:I32,W3,E4:E32)*SUMIFS(C4:C32,W3,E4:E32) and it is now giving me a Value error

Comment: It won't allow you to do those calculations within Sumifs.

Comment: how do i achieve what im trying to do then?

Comment: Do you have some small sample data with expected output?

Answer (score 2):

By using the sumproduct function, I can achieve my goal with the formula looking like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(I4:I32,C4:C32*(E4:E32=W3))
```